# curl API call through python

Tags: python, api, curl, post

I am working with an API to get invoices information, and de example showed in the documentation is from Curl:

```
[HEAD] Authorization: Basic base64(Consumer Key:Consumer Secret) 
[HEAD] Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded 
[POST] grant_type=client_credentials

echo -n "djaR21PGoYp1iyK2n2ACOH9REdUb:ObRsAJWOL4fv2Tp27D1vd8fB3Ote" | base64
```

The code above returns this string: ZGphUjIxUEdvWXAxaXlLMm4yQUNPSDlSRWRVYjpPYlJzQUpXT0w0ZnYyVHAyN0QxdmQ4ZkIzT3RlCg

```
curl -k -d "grant_type=client_credentials" \
-H "Authorization: Basic ZGphUjIxUEdvWXAxaXlLMm4yQUNPSDlSRWRVYjpPYlJzQUpXT0w0ZnYyVHAyN0QxdmQ4ZkIzT3RlCg" \
https://gateway.apiserpro.serpro.gov.br/token
```

How do I convert this do Python?

Comment: Welcome to SO! SO isn't a coding service. You have to try first and then ask specific questions related to your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Basic ZGphUjIxUEdvWXAxaXlLMm4yQUNPSDlSRWRVYjpPYlJzQUpXT0w0ZnYyVHAyN0QxdmQ4ZkIzT3RlCg',
}

data = {
  'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
}

response = requests.post('https://gateway.apiserpro.serpro.gov.br/token', headers=headers, data=data)
```

A helpful resource for converting CURL to Python requests is: https://curl.trillworks.com/